# how to fix the paggination problem in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I wan't to create pagination in my project, but I have some problems.
I'm using a `.htaccess` in CodeIgniter. It makes my url not use `index.php`
and then I have created the pagination rules in the controller: `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/project/member'`.
It makes my project unable to use the pagination, but if I use `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/project/member/index'`, the pagination works.
The case is my page can't show the css program, because I'm using bootstrap in this case, how can I fix the problem when I'm using the "index" and not using "index" in the `base_url`?

Comment: go in the application/config/config.php and find index_page remove index.php leave empty.

Comment: i've do that. the index_page is empty now. but when i move to another page(click next in paggination), its make my view in website disorganized because i not add the index in the $config[base_url].

Answer (score 1):

i've clear the problem
this is a silly mistake
in the header, i not make the link using `<?= base_url('')?>`
then, i use all `<link ref` to the css using `<?= base_url('')?>`, well done
its work

thanks for all respon here

Answer (score 0):

Use below code, it will work

```
    $this->load->library("pagination");

    $config = array();
    $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "review";
    $config["total_rows"] = $this->blog->getReviewCount();
    $config["per_page"] = 10;
    $config["uri_segment"] = 2;
    $config['full_tag_open'] = "<ul class='pagination'>";
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
    $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
    $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';



    $config['prev_link'] = 'Previous';
    $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';


    $config['next_link'] = 'Next';
    $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $page = ($this->uri->segment(2)) ? $this->uri->segment(2) : 0;
    $data['title'] = "Review";
    $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
    $data['review'] = $this->blog->getReviews($config["per_page"], $page);
    $this->load->view("review", $data);
```

Comment: thankyou for answer, but its not work for me

"04 Page Not Found
The page you requested was not found."

but, if i add "index" after riview in base_url() . "review".. its work with same problem, the CSS or page view in disarray

my problem is not in the make the paggination problem, but when i move the page to next and the CSS view is disarray

Answer (score 0):

@Lin when you take out index.php from $config[base_url] you will need to place an .htaccess file on your root folder(I mean where your index.php file is found)

Create a .htacces file and put in the code below:

```
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1
```

When it doesn't fix it let me know. It might be your pagination configuration is not set well. Looking at @Justin-j gave it should have worked.

Comment: thankyou for your respon @Oteng Kwame, but i've do that and its still not work
i've place my .htaccess file on my root folder.
example : 
project/application/controller/member/index
my root is in project folder, i place my .htaccess in project/,htaccess

Answer (score 0):

in this case, can i access using different url with same page?
example:

- localhost/project/index.php/member
- localhost/project/member

with use the .htaccess like this in my root folder

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: i mean can i get the same view in my page with the different url like that? because if you try this using first and second url, that's will show you different view of your page